# How to disable firefox/mozilla global extensions access

Tags: firefox, sandbox

I need to sandbox Mozilla Firefox and it seems that write access is required for "~/Library/Application\ Support/Mozilla/Extensions/" on Mac OS. I want to turn off this feature.

Is it possible somehow to disable access to "~/Library/Application\ Support/Mozilla/Extensions/", i.e in a way disabling access to global extensions. Perhaps a preference of some sort?

Answer (score 0):

For reference, this is the [directory for externally installed extensions on Mac OS X](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Installing_extensions#Mac_OS_X). From what I can tell, the write access to this directory is very limited - Firefox is merely trying to ensure that this directory exists (and a failure is ok). After that it will accept any extensions installed in this directory but will not try to write to it.

As to disabling this functionality: the directories are determined by [nsXREDirProvider.cpp](http://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/file/87da67ee3e59/toolkit/xre/nsXREDirProvider.cpp#l319), the only way to disable them there would be the `--disable-system-extension-dirs` compile option.

But `XPIProvider.jsm` where these directories are used has additional logic to decide which install scopes will be used, based on [`extensions.enabledScopes` preference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Addons/Add-on_Manager/AddonManager#Installation_scopes). This preference doesn't exist by default, it needs to be created as an integer. Setting it to 1 will leave only the profile directory as extension source, all global extension sources will be disabled (including `XREUSysExt` that you are asking about - that one falls into `SCOPE_USER` category).